# Meaning of the phrase in comic

Tags: meaning

Here's a context: one officer is saying, that all work at the war was done by infantry. His friend agreed with him. The other officer (lower rank) is saying:

"Herr general: we who work behind the front line hear often how wonderful the landsers are. But there are tasks that fall beyond the scope of infantry. There are battles that are won by iron will, not brute strength and by all means, have your friend pull rank on me. Have me dismissed".

I can understand the first part, but completely lost at the second. what's the meaning of "have" here?

Comment: Please read the editing and make sure the paragraph is right. Sounds like it was translated from German. All the work during the war.

Comment: [You can] have me dismissed = you can order that I am to be dismissed.

Comment: It is "have" as used in the causative. i.e. " I had him dismissed."

Answer (score 0):

There are several meanings of the word "have" and the [online Collins Dictionary entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have) has many of them. One of these is

> If you have someone do something, you persuade, cause, or order them to do it.

with these examples

> If you happen to talk to him, have him call me.

and

> The bridge is not as impressive as some guides would have you believe.

This is the sense in which "have" is used in the film so you could re-write the line as "*...by all means cause, persuade or instruct your friend to pull rank on me...*"